# Slick Responsivo

Tags: javascript

Não estou conseguindo criar um slick responsivo, não tenho muita experiêcia com HTML.

```
<div class="carousel-logistics">
    <div class="slick-logistics">
        <div class="logistics"><img class="img-fluid" src=""
            /></div>
        <div class="logistics"><img class="img-fluid" src=""
            /></div>
        <div class="logistics"><img class="img-fluid" src=""
            /></div>
        <div class="logistics"><img class="img-fluid" src=""
            /></div>
    </div>
</div>

if( $(".slick-logistics").length ){
    $(".slick-logistics p").remove();
    $(".slick-logistics").slick({
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 4,
        autoplay: true
    });
}
```

Comment: Descreva melhor o problema, não da pra entender muito bem a sua duvida.

Comment: gostaria que quando chegasse na resolucao de tablet o carousel mostrasse 2 imagens

Answer (score 0):

O [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) possui uma propriedade chamado `responsive`, lá você determina a quantidade de imagens deseja exibir para cada resolução, como não há um padrão estabelecido nos tablets, você pode estipular manualmente. Veja:

```
$('.responsive').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4, // aqui é o padrão
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024, // aqui define até que largura será as configs abaixo
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
  ]
});
```